# hint for minimising $L_p$ norm

Tags: optimization

$$u^* = \arg\min_{u} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{8} |X(i)-u|^p\right)^{1/p},$$ I need hint solving above equation. I tried deriving with $u$ but I think it's not the right way.
where $p\in \{1,\infty\}$,
$X(i)=i$

Comment: You need to define your terms. $X(i)$, arg?

Comment: @herbsteinberg X={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, argmin is the value of u which minimises the above equation

Comment: The question is not clear. From your comment, $X(i)$ takes values from $1,2,...,8$ but $X(i) \ne X(j)$ if $i \ne j$  or not?

Comment: @NN2 Yes, $X(1)=1,...,X(8)=8$

Comment: @username yes $X(i)$ is mentioned above

Comment: So $X(i)$ is just $i$? You should edit the clarification into the question, not in the comments. Also, you cannot substitute $p=\infty$ in the expression

Comment: So you are looking for the minimum of $f$ where 
$$
f :x\to \left(\sum_{k=1}^8 |k-x|^p\right)^\frac1p.
$$
for all $p\in(1,\infty)$ ? The answer is the middle $u=\frac 95$. It is a convex map.

Comment: @username for  $p->\infty$ can you write the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is equivalent to minimize

$$S = \sum_k^8 |k-u|^p$$

> *Lemma*: for $a,b$ positive and $p>1$
> $$a^p+b^p\ge 2^{1-p} |a+b|^p$$
> *Proof*: Applying the [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Finite_form) to the convex function $f(x) = x^p$  (this function is convex because $f''(x) = p(p-1)x^{p-2}>0$ for $p\in (1,+\infty)$):
> $$\left|\frac{a}{2}  \right|^p+\left|\frac{b}{2}  \right|^p\ge \left|\frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{2}  \right|^p$$
> or $a^p+b^p\ge 2^{1-p} |a+b|^p$.
> The equality occurs if and only if $a=b$ Q.E.D.

Apply the lemma to 4 couples $(a,b) = ((u-k),(8-k-u))$ with $k\in \{1,2,3,4  \}$
$$|k-u|^p+|8-k-u|^p \ge 2^{1-p} |(u-k)+(8-k-u)|^p= 2^{1-p}(8-2k)^p$$

Hence
\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{k=1}^8 |k-u|^p \\ 
&= \sum_{k=1}^4 (|k-u|^p+|8-k-u|^p) \ge \sum_{k=1}^4 2^{1-p}(8-2k)^p = 2\sum_{k=1}^4 k^p\\
\end{align}

The equality occurs if and only if $u = \frac{9}{2}$.

Return back to the initial problem, $$\arg\min_{u} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{8} |k-u|^p\right)^{1/p} = \frac{9}{2}$$

Comment: does this work for $p->\infty$ case too?

Comment: @anfjnlnl yes, it work for all $p \ge 1$.